# adjust margin-top proportionally depending on distance of image from bottom of div

Tags: html, css, image

I have a javascript function which resizes images, dynamically generated on a page via php, to ensure that they fill the width and height of the div that contains them. Unfortunately, I have no control over the width to height ratio of the image, and some images could not be stretched to cover the height of the div without appearing distorted.

My solution to this is to attempt to add a margin-top css parameter using javascript, assigning the remainder of the distance between the bottom of the image and the height of the div to be the value of that parameter (e.g. maxHeight-imageHeight). However, using this method the image disappears beyond the bounds of the div.

I was wondering if anyone had any solutions to this. Either a better way to do it, or a way to make this method work?

Comment: You could set CSS via JS like: `background-image` of those `div`-s to the specified images, and set `background-size: 100%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want fill your div by image without distort you must fill it by width or height of image which on closer to the div size.

```
.imageInDiv{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
   }
```

And if you want your image to be in center of it's parent div:

```
.parentDiv{
   display:flex;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   justify-content:center;
   -webkit-justify-content:center;
   align-items:center;
   -webkit-align-items:center;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I have been trying to work that out how to centre an image both horizontally and vertically for days. I could only seem to manage one or the other but not both.

Comment: You welcome!. Now you could remove 'javascript' from your question title because it is not related to js. Then your question may help others.